# ADAM Load Balancing

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, adam

I'm interested in load balancing an ADAM instance but don't even know where to begin.  Documentation on the web is pretty scarce.  Has anyone done this before and more importantly can point me in the right direction for a How To?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you just need to install another ADAM. During the the first part of the installation, you just indicate, that it's not a new directory, but a second server from an existing directory.